# Distribution of Brownian motion at a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X,Y$ be independent Brownian motions, and let
$$
T_a = \inf\{t\geq 0 : Y_t = a\}
$$
for some $a > 0$. My question is how can I find the distribution of $X_{T_a}$? The hints I have are to use characteristic functions and the Laplace transform
$$
\mathbb E[e^{-\lambda T_a}] = e^{-a\sqrt \lambda}.
$$
I don't see how this helps, though. Any advice or hints are appreciated!

Comment: In my opinion, this is a very interesting question. If you go to Yuval Peres' webpage, he has a book about Brownian Motion that he co-wrote with Peter Morters. In this book, he gives three different methods of finding the distribution of $X_{T_a}$. The first time it is proven as Theorem 2.37, and then it is given as exercises 2.19 and 7.5. Here is the book: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/peres/brbook.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look at that.

Comment: This is in many textbooks. The formula for the Laplace transform of $T_a$ should read $$E[e^{-\lambda T_a}] = e^{-a\sqrt{2\lambda}},
$$ then write $$E[e^{isX_{T_a}}]=\int_0^\infty E[e^{isX_t}]\,dP_{T_a}(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-s^2t/2}\,dP_{T_a}(t)=E[e^{-s^2T_a/2}]=\ldots$$